# How to set the script execution directory in Padre debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging, directory, padre

How to set the script execution directory?

For example, the script `main.pl` is located in a `scripts/` directory. The file to be processed is `data.txt`, located in a `data/` directory.

Then, `cd data/` and invoke the script using `../scripts/main.pl -i data.txt`

When debugging the script in Padre debugger, the execution directory is the script's location `scripts/`. The command args `-i data.txt` can be set through the Preferences dialog, but in order for this to work, it needs to be changed to `-i ../data/data.txt`

How can one set the execution directory ti be other than the script's location?

Comment: I have not used Padre before, but I was able to install it now. It seems that you can use the *"Run in directory"* option from the *"Debug launch Parameters"* dialog to set the script execution directory

Comment: @HåkonHægland - Wow.. wait... where do you see that dialog?

Comment: I select menu *"Debug->Debug launch options"* then I get the dialog

Comment: That's weird, I don't have that option in my Debug menu. What Padre version are you using? I use Padre 0.94 (32-bit) on Windows, installed from the `dwimperl-5.14.2.1-v7-32bit.exe` installer.

Comment: I installed [version 1.00](https://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Padre/Padre-1.00.tar.gz) and I am using Ubuntu 18.10. So it seems this option is a feature that was added recently (after 0.94)?

Comment: Mmmmm.... Seems like the latest (official?) Windows release (2012!!) lags behind the Ubuntu release, unfortunately.

Comment: Downloaded the tarball but no obvious way to build on Windows (and the documentation is atrocious), so I just let go. If you make your comments an answer, I can upvote (and accept) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can one set the execution directory to be other than the script's location?

According to the comments, you seem to be running Padre version 0.94 for Windows, then apparently it is not possible to set the directory (at least from the GUI).

However, the feature seems to have been added to Padre later. I installed Padre version 1.00 on my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop running Perl 5.29.8 (with thread support). Then there is an option 
 *"Run in directory"* from the *"Debug launch Parameters"* dialog where you can set the script execution directory.